# Problem with roscore?

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well this is a new one. I updated my packages, and now roscore doesn't work. Here's the error code:

```
allenh1@muri-pc7:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/allenh1/.ros/log/b450054e-c45a-11e1-b560-0025648c1ab0/roslaunch-muri-pc7-2554.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosversion", line 76, in <module>
    version = rosstack.get_stack_version(stack_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 359, in get_stack_version
    return get_stack_version_by_dir(self.get_path(stack))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 412, in get_stack_version_by_dir
    m = parse_manifest_file(stack_dir, STACK_FILE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/manifest.py", line 343, in parse_manifest_file
    return parse_manifest(manifest_name, f.read(), filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/manifest.py", line 404, in parse_manifest
    m.author = _check('author')(p, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/manifest.py", line 67, in check
    raise InvalidManifest("Invalid manifest file [%s]: must have a single '%s' element"%(filename, name))
rospkg.manifest.InvalidManifest: Invalid manifest file [/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/stack.xml]: must have a single 'author' element
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion ros] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion ros" name="rosversion"/>
```

What have I done now...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37697/problem-with-roscore?/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duplicate of [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/37397/update-fuerte-to-1810-breaks-rospkg/#37402) question. Just do a `pip install -U rospkg`.

See this [more completed answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/49143/problems-with-rqt-groovy-ubuntu/?answer=49153#post-id-49153)

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-02**:
I think we should stop recommending easy_install. Use pip, it's better.

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-02**:
@joq +1: `pip` has 'uninstall', `easy_install` doesn't. Also `pip freeze | grep XXX` is nice.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-02**:
Both have their problems but you are right, I should stop mentioning easy_install.

**Comment by [Vittorio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/2132/vittorio88/) on 2012-07-15**:
Actually the Question you linked to later says the correct solution is to remove rospkg, not reinstall it. Go to link to view full answer.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-15**:
That's not true. Look at the last sentence of my answer, in the edit. The correct solution for now is to update rospkg since it will be updated anyway when rosdep or rosrelease is installed or updated.

**Comment by [arushi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23725/arushi/) on 2015-08-31**:
pip install -U rospkg. this is'nt helping me out ..........i have reinstalled the roscore but nothing is happening still showing keyboard interrupts